# Removing unwanted elements from GPX (XML) files using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I have a number of gpx (XML) files with extraneous tags that serve no purpose & I'd like to get rid of them & then rewrite the files.

Opening and parsing them with BeautifulSoup (v4) is trivial, but I'm now blundering about trying to find how to delete the tags.

In the example fragment given, the tags I want to remove are the entire `<name>n</name>` (where n is an integer) tags within **trkseg**. (i.e. not just the value)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<gpx version="1.1">
<metadata>
<name>A Name</name>
<desc>A Description</desc>
<author>
<name>Another Name</name>
<email>emailaddr@nonexistentdomain.com</email>
</author>
<time>2018-10-27T17:58:45Z</time>
</metadata>
<trk>
<desc>
"Walk Number", "Start Date", "Start Time", "Elapsed Time", "Miles","Kilometers", "Steps", "Calories"
2,"27 Oct 2018","1:18:05 pm","4 hours15 minutes29 seconds",13.37,21.52,33436,1,212
</desc>
<trkseg>
<name>2</name>
<trkpt lat="32.01333283" lon="-28.61624884">
<ele>274.0</ele>
<time>2018-10-27T13:18:05Z</time>
</trkpt>
<name>2</name>
<trkpt lat="32.01325155" lon="-28.61617729">
<ele>260.0</ele>
<time>2018-10-27T13:18:32Z</time>
</trkpt>
<name>2</name>
<trkpt lat="32.01317277" lon="-28.6162623">
<ele>264.0</ele>
<time>2018-10-27T13:18:38Z</time>
</trkpt>
<name>2</name>
<trkpt lat="32.01308939" lon="-28.61634673">
<ele>272.0</ele>
<time>2018-10-27T13:18:46Z</time>
</trkpt>
<name>2</name>
<trkpt lat="32.01300121" lon="-28.61649587">
<ele>270.0</ele>
<time>2018-10-27T13:18:54Z</time>
</trkpt>
</trkseg>
</trk>
</gpx>
```

Answers on SO and elsewhere for removing tags don't seem to match this use case & I haven't found the BS documentation helpful (my flaw rather than that of the docs I'm sure).

(Because the files are fairly simple and consistently formatted, I could use **awk** or **sed** to remove these tags, but I'd like to know how manage this in BS in case I encounter something less straightforward in the future)

Anyway, I've only got this far:

```
# "gpx" is the data fragment given above
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS 

gpxml = BS(gpx, 'xml')

# and I can do this to find all the unwanted tags in <trkseg>

unwanted = gpxml.trkseg.name
print(unwanted)
[<name>2</name>, <name>2</name>, <name>2</name>, <name>2</name>, <name>2</name>]

# and I can do this to iterate the trkseg and print trkpt & name by turn

for el in gpxml.trkseg:
    print(el)
```

But at this point I've run out of understanding.

I think I perhaps need to use BeautifulSoup's **decompose()** method somehow ?

I'm using BeautifulSoup because I find lxml.etree even less comprehensible ( I'm not a programmer by either employment or nature)

Answer (score 2):

Using ElementTree

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gpx version="1.1">
   <metadata>
      <name>A Name</name>
      <desc>A Description</desc>
      <author>
         <name>Another Name</name>
         <email>emailaddr@nonexistentdomain.com</email>
      </author>
      <time>2018-10-27T17:58:45Z</time>
   </metadata>
   <trk>
      <desc>"Walk Number", "Start Date", "Start Time", "Elapsed Time", "Miles","Kilometers", "Steps", "Calories"
2,"27 Oct 2018","1:18:05 pm","4 hours15 minutes29 seconds",13.37,21.52,33436,1,212</desc>
      <trkseg>
         <name>2</name>
         <trkpt lat="32.01333283" lon="-28.61624884">
            <ele>274.0</ele>
            <time>2018-10-27T13:18:05Z</time>
         </trkpt>
         <name>2</name>
         <trkpt lat="32.01325155" lon="-28.61617729">
            <ele>260.0</ele>
            <time>2018-10-27T13:18:32Z</time>
         </trkpt>
         <name>2</name>
         <trkpt lat="32.01317277" lon="-28.6162623">
            <ele>264.0</ele>
            <time>2018-10-27T13:18:38Z</time>
         </trkpt>
         <name>2</name>
         <trkpt lat="32.01308939" lon="-28.61634673">
            <ele>272.0</ele>
            <time>2018-10-27T13:18:46Z</time>
         </trkpt>
         <name>2</name>
         <trkpt lat="32.01300121" lon="-28.61649587">
            <ele>270.0</ele>
            <time>2018-10-27T13:18:54Z</time>
         </trkpt>
      </trkseg>
   </trk>
</gpx>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
trkseg_lst = root.findall('.//trkseg')
for entry in trkseg_lst:
    for element in list(entry):
        if element.tag == 'name':
            entry.remove(element)
ET.dump(root)
```

output

```
<gpx version="1.1">
   <metadata>
      <name>A Name</name>
      <desc>A Description</desc>
      <author>
         <name>Another Name</name>
         <email>emailaddr@nonexistentdomain.com</email>
      </author>
      <time>2018-10-27T17:58:45Z</time>
   </metadata>
   <trk>
      <desc>"Walk Number", "Start Date", "Start Time", "Elapsed Time", "Miles","Kilometers", "Steps", "Calories"
2,"27 Oct 2018","1:18:05 pm","4 hours15 minutes29 seconds",13.37,21.52,33436,1,212</desc>
      <trkseg>
         <trkpt lat="32.01333283" lon="-28.61624884">
            <ele>274.0</ele>
            <time>2018-10-27T13:18:05Z</time>
         </trkpt>
         <trkpt lat="32.01325155" lon="-28.61617729">
            <ele>260.0</ele>
            <time>2018-10-27T13:18:32Z</time>
         </trkpt>
         <trkpt lat="32.01317277" lon="-28.6162623">
            <ele>264.0</ele>
            <time>2018-10-27T13:18:38Z</time>
         </trkpt>
         <trkpt lat="32.01308939" lon="-28.61634673">
            <ele>272.0</ele>
            <time>2018-10-27T13:18:46Z</time>
         </trkpt>
         <trkpt lat="32.01300121" lon="-28.61649587">
            <ele>270.0</ele>
            <time>2018-10-27T13:18:54Z</time>
         </trkpt>
      </trkseg>
   </trk>
</gpx>
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove a tag you should use the `decompose` method. Then, by a applying a filter, you can choose those tags satisfying your condition, `<name>2</name>`.

**NB** `decompose` acts on the whole tree so you original object will be changed

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

gpxml = '' # from above

soup = BS(gpxml, 'xml')

for tag in soup.find_all('name', string=True):
    if str(tag.string) == '2':
        tag.decompose()

soup = soup.gpx.extract() # skip the xml-header
print(soup)
```

Comment: as pointed out in the solution of Ram, bs4 add by default the "headers" of the document. Such are parser dependent. For xml will be only smt like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`. If it is not needed one can remove for example with `extract` method

Answer (score 0):

Solution with BeautifulSoup.

Using `decompose()` method remove the `<name>` tags iteratively from `<trkseg>` tag.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
gpx = '''
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<gpx version="1.1">
<metadata>
<name>A Name</name>
<desc>A Description</desc>
<author>
<name>Another Name</name>
<email>emailaddr@nonexistentdomain.com</email>
</author>
<time>2018-10-27T17:58:45Z</time>
</metadata>
<trk>
<desc>
"Walk Number", "Start Date", "Start Time", "Elapsed Time", "Miles","Kilometers", "Steps", "Calories"
2,"27 Oct 2018","1:18:05 pm","4 hours15 minutes29 seconds",13.37,21.52,33436,1,212
</desc>
<trkseg>
<name>2</name>
<trkpt lat="32.01333283" lon="-28.61624884">
<ele>274.0</ele>
<time>2018-10-27T13:18:05Z</time>
</trkpt>
<name>2</name>
<trkpt lat="32.01325155" lon="-28.61617729">
<ele>260.0</ele>
<time>2018-10-27T13:18:32Z</time>
</trkpt>
<name>2</name>
<trkpt lat="32.01317277" lon="-28.6162623">
<ele>264.0</ele>
<time>2018-10-27T13:18:38Z</time>
</trkpt>
<name>2</name>
<trkpt lat="32.01308939" lon="-28.61634673">
<ele>272.0</ele>
<time>2018-10-27T13:18:46Z</time>
</trkpt>
<name>2</name>
<trkpt lat="32.01300121" lon="-28.61649587">
<ele>270.0</ele>
<time>2018-10-27T13:18:54Z</time>
</trkpt>
</trkseg>
</trk>
</gpx>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(gpx, 'xml')
t = soup.find('trkseg')
while t.find('name') is not None:
    t.find('name').decompose()

print(soup)
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><gpx version="1.1">
<metadata>
<name>A Name</name>
<desc>A Description</desc>
<author>
<name>Another Name</name>
<email>emailaddr@nonexistentdomain.com</email>
</author>
<time>2018-10-27T17:58:45Z</time>
</metadata>
<trk>
<desc>
"Walk Number", "Start Date", "Start Time", "Elapsed Time", "Miles","Kilometers", "Steps", "Calories"
2,"27 Oct 2018","1:18:05 pm","4 hours15 minutes29 seconds",13.37,21.52,33436,1,212
</desc>
<trkseg>

<trkpt lat="32.01333283" lon="-28.61624884">
<ele>274.0</ele>
<time>2018-10-27T13:18:05Z</time>
</trkpt>

<trkpt lat="32.01325155" lon="-28.61617729">
<ele>260.0</ele>
<time>2018-10-27T13:18:32Z</time>
</trkpt>

<trkpt lat="32.01317277" lon="-28.6162623">
<ele>264.0</ele>
<time>2018-10-27T13:18:38Z</time>
</trkpt>

<trkpt lat="32.01308939" lon="-28.61634673">
<ele>272.0</ele>
<time>2018-10-27T13:18:46Z</time>
</trkpt>

<trkpt lat="32.01300121" lon="-28.61649587">
<ele>270.0</ele>
<time>2018-10-27T13:18:54Z</time>
</trkpt>
</trkseg>
</trk>
</gpx>
```

Comment: if you do soup = BeautifulSoup(gpx, 'xml') (nb 'xml' not 'lxml') then the html tags don't get added (in the version I'm using anyway)

Comment: Ok. I didn't know that. But I see using ```xml``` parser adds this - ```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>``` to the soup. The final soup has two XML prologs.

Comment: the head and body tags depends on the choice of the parser, in your case lxml. With xml you get only the xml-header

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you need to modify or transform XML files, consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/), the special-purpose industry language. Specifically for your use case, run the [Identity Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) followed by an empty template for the nodes to remove from tree using specific conditional logic.

Python can run XSLT 1.0 with `lxml` package. No loops needed with this approach!

```py
import lxml.etree as lx

# PARSE XML AND XSLT
doc = lx.parse("Input.gpx")

style = lx.fromstring(
b'''
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- IDENTITY TRANSFORM -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- EMPTY TEMPLATE -->
    <xsl:template match="name[text()=number(text())]"/>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
''')

# INITIALIZE TRANSFORMER AND APPLY IT
transformer = lx.XSLT(style)
result = transformer(doc)
```

**Output**

```
print(result)

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gpx version="1.1">
  <metadata>
    <name>A Name</name>
    <desc>A Description</desc>
    <author>
      <name>Another Name</name>
      <email>emailaddr@nonexistentdomain.com</email>
    </author>
    <time>2018-10-27T17:58:45Z</time>
  </metadata>
  <trk>
    <desc>
"Walk Number", "Start Date", "Start Time", "Elapsed Time", "Miles","Kilometers", "Steps", "Calories"
2,"27 Oct 2018","1:18:05 pm","4 hours15 minutes29 seconds",13.37,21.52,33436,1,212
</desc>
    <trkseg>
      <trkpt lat="32.01333283" lon="-28.61624884">
        <ele>274.0</ele>
        <time>2018-10-27T13:18:05Z</time>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt lat="32.01325155" lon="-28.61617729">
        <ele>260.0</ele>
        <time>2018-10-27T13:18:32Z</time>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt lat="32.01317277" lon="-28.6162623">
        <ele>264.0</ele>
        <time>2018-10-27T13:18:38Z</time>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt lat="32.01308939" lon="-28.61634673">
        <ele>272.0</ele>
        <time>2018-10-27T13:18:46Z</time>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt lat="32.01300121" lon="-28.61649587">
        <ele>270.0</ele>
        <time>2018-10-27T13:18:54Z</time>
      </trkpt>
    </trkseg>
  </trk>
</gpx>
```

Save to file

```py
with open('Output.gpx', 'wb') as f: 
    f.write(result)
```